# Can I create an object without a name in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a structure that looks like this:

```
var set_2 =  {
    nameofSet : 'French greetings',
    category: 'languages',
    cards : [
        {
            front : 'bonjour',
            back : 'dzien dobry'
        },
        {
            front : 'bonne nuit',
            back : 'dobranoc'
        },
        {
            front : 'bon soir',
            back : 'dobry wieczor'
        }
    ]
}
```

I can iterate over them in a loop like this:

```
 var cards = set_2.cards;
 for (k = 0;k<cards.length;k++) {
     var frontSide = cards[k].front;
     var backSide = cards[k].back;
 }
```

Do I assume correctly that in the cards array I have a couple of objects without names?

If so, how can I push more objects like that to the cards array without giving them names? I want to create those objects in a for loop.

Comment: What? _I have a couple of objects without names_. Can you elaborate some more?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir It's about these objects inside `cards` array. They are not *named* - I bet that he means that they are not assigned separately to variables.

Comment: my guess is oneday is talking about associative arrays (objects) when he refers to "names".  But I'm only speculating.

Comment: @Kinduser thank you, this is exactly what I meant. I don't want to assign them to any sort of a variable with a name.

Comment: By "names", you mean "keys". JavaScript objects are key-value collections. The key to access your card collection is `cards`, so that's how you access the collection.

Comment: Read about **object literals**!

Comment: @ChrisZimmerman this I know, but thanks anyway. `cards` is the key and the array is its value, what I meant is that I don't want to create something like `var newCard = {front:something, back:something}` and then push the `newCard` variable into the `cards` array. I wanted to push it without creating the variable with `newCard` name (solved now, thank you)

@ibrahimmahrir I will, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by names, but you can push more objects into the array as such:

```
set_2.cards.push({front: 'front', back: 'back'});
```

Comment: @oneday It doesn't make any sense. Where do you store that values to push into the `cards` array? Maybe there's no need to use `push` method, but e.g. - `concat`.

Comment: What I have are divs of the same class ('.card'), each with two textareas with the front and back values for the cards. I need to loop through the existing `.card` classes, extract the values of their textareas and push them as values for `front` and `back` properties. Each `.card` class would correspond with a `{front:something,back:something}`element in the cards array.

Answer (score 1):

> Q: Do I assume correctly that in the cards array I have a couple of
> objects without names?

A: Yes, they do not have property names like object properties do, but they each have an index, like arrays have, as in 0, 1, 2.
Or rather:

```
set_2.cards[0]
set_2.cards[1]
set_2.cards[2]
```

> Q: If so, how can I push more objects like that to the cards array
> without giving them names?

A: As the accepted answer says:

```
set_2.cards.push({front: 'front', back: 'back'});
```

These new objects that you push into the array will not have names, but they will have indices(or "indexes").

**In summation, an element of an array is indicated by its index number(JavaScript Number), while an entry in an object is indicated by its property name(JavaScript String).**

Answer (score 1):

You can't create an object without names in it. Either object with names or just a normal array but you can create object with name followed by arrays inside.

#### Object -> object_name -> Array -> object -> object_name -> Array

```
var set_2 =  {
    nameofSet : 'French greetings',
    category: 'languages',
    cards : [
             {
              front: ['bonjour', 'bonne nuit', 'bon soir'],
              back:  ['dzien dobry', 'dobranoc' 'dobry wieczor']
             }
            ]     
}
```

'bonjour'

```
console.log(set_2.cards[0].front[0]);
```

'dobranoc'

```
console.log(set_2.cards[0].back[1]);
```

push into front

```
set_2.cards[0].front.push('Hello');
```

push into back

```
set_2.cards[0].back.push('Hello');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `push()` method like this

```
  var set_2 =  {
    nameofSet : 'French greetings',
    category: 'languages',
    cards : [
        {
            front : 'bonjour',
            back : 'dzien dobry'
        },
        {
            front : 'bonne nuit',
            back : 'dobranoc'
        },
        {
            front : 'bon soir',
            back : 'dobry wieczor'
        }
    ]
}

var cards = set_2.cards;
var obj = { front:"front1", back:"back1"};
cards.push(obj);

 for (k = 0;k<cards.length;k++) {
     var frontSide = cards[k].front;
     var backSide = cards[k].back;
     console.log(backSide);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the question about having a few objects without names. If I understand it correctly, you have one main object. Its name is "set_2". The rest such as "nameofSet", "category", and "cards" are the names of properties of the object.

"cards" has an array value that appears to have empty objects with the "front" and "back"properties, if you are asking this*.